# Twilio -- How to get link to media file sent via MMS?

Tags: twilio

I am using $messages = $client->account->sms_messages->getIterator(0, 50, array()); and variations thereof to get the text from txt messages.

However, when the message is an image the result is blank.

How do I go about getting the link to the media? I would prefer it not be displayed inline but rather as a link such as "Click here for media." and then open a new window to the image, audio, video, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

If you want to access the url of the media for a message you would use this code:

```
  $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
  foreach ($client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array()) as $message) {
    foreach ($message->media as $media) {
        echo "http://api.twilio.com" .  $media->uri;
    }
  }
```

In this code access the [media subresources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media) for our message and then loop over them. I'm just echoing the results but you could do whatever you'd like with this data.